# Stuck with this proof of an equivalence of two propositional calculus formulas

Tags: propositional-calculus

How do I prove that
$$\neg(\neg p\to (q\wedge p)) \equiv p\to (\neg q\wedge \neg p)$$

Edit 1: I need to do this prove without using a truth table. A table does indeed show that they are equivalent, but I cannot think of any basic or derivative laws that can help me do this. I believe I must be missing something here.

Edit 2: I started from
$$(p\rightarrow\lnot q)\land\lnot p$$
$$\equiv (\lnot p\lor\lnot q)\land\lnot p$$
$$\equiv\lnot (p\land q)\land\lnot p$$
$$\equiv\lnot ((p\land q)\lor p)$$
$$\equiv\lnot (\lnot p\rightarrow (q\land p))$$
and got stuck right there.

Comment: Truth table. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Specifically without a truth table. I'll add this to the question. My apologies.

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, please provide context for your query. You can find information on how to ask questions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thank you. I have added my workings in an edit.

Comment: I feel like I should make a "propositional-calculus-without-truth-tables" tab like I did "limits-without-lhopital" hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sure way to solve problems like that is to build normal forms. Thus,

$\neg(\neg p\rightarrow(q\land p))\equiv\neg p\land\neg(q\land p)\equiv\neg p\land(\neg q\vee\neg p).$

This is the CNF of the left formula. Similarly, for the formula in the right we get

$p\rightarrow(\neg q\land\neg p)\equiv\neg p\vee(\neg q\land\neg p)\equiv(\neg p\vee\neg p)\land(\neg q\vee\neg p)\equiv\neg p\land(\neg q\vee\neg p).$

Both of them are equivalent to $\neg p\land(\neg q\vee\neg p)$, hence, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. This was what I needed, but may I know if there is a derivative "law" that tells us $$\lnot (P\rightarrow Q)\equiv P\land\lnot Q$$ Could this be related to the Reductio ad absurdum law? If so, I am unsure of that particular law. All I know is that $$p\rightarrow q\equiv (p\land\lnot q)\rightarrow contradiction$$

Comment: This follows from a chain  of equivalences $\neg(P\rightarrow Q)\equiv\neg(\neg P\vee Q)\equiv(\neg\neg P\land\neg Q)\equiv(P\land\neg Q)$. The first step based on a well-known equivalence $P\rightarrow Q\equiv\neg P\vee Q$ and second one on De Morgan's law.

Comment: Thank you! My frustration blinded myself from seeing something this simple. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I accepted the answer, but since I'm a new user, I don't meet the 15 rep required to upvote.